# Is it possible to Filter Graphs in a way that they at most contain requested Data?

Tags: sparql

Let me start with an example query to explain my problem:

```
SELECT ?g ?s ?p ?o WHERE
{
  {GRAPH ?g
    {   ?s ?p ?o.
        OPTIONAL{ ?s
          ab:temperature ?temperature.}
      FILTER (?temperature = 20)
      FILTER NOT EXISTS {?s ab:person ?person}
    }
  }
}
```

This query gives me all graphs (in this case representing context data) that have a temperature of 20  but don't have a person associated. My problem is I want to query the graphs for certain optional properties but they shouldn't have any other properties. At the time of the query I only know the OPTIONAL part but I don't know which additional property might be there. Is there an easy way to do this with SPARQL or is that something that would be easier to check after I received the graph and converted it to an object which I can handle with my programm?

Comment: is the mismatch between the vars `?temp` and `?temperature` intentional?

Comment: "My problem is I want to query the graphs for certain optional properties but they shouldn't have any other properties." You have in your query "?s ?p ?o".  That's going to get all the properties of ?s.  Are you trying to include only certain values of ?p, or to exclude certain values of ?p ?

Comment: I want to include only certain values of ?p. I think Jörn already has the solution I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you are searching for graphs that only have that subjects with some properties but not others. In that case i'd run something like this:

```
SELECT ?g ?s ?p ?o WHERE {
 GRAPH ?g {
  ?s ?p ?o.
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {
   ?s ?bad [] .
   FILTER (?bad NOT IN ( ab:temperature, ... ) )
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: This looks good. Do I need need the "FILTER( ?p IN ( ab:temperature , ... ) )" line? The next Filter looks like it would do what I need.